# How to query an association table in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'd like to extract only pairs of keys stored in an association table in SQLAlchemy. One way is to create an association class and make something like `session.query(Assoc).all()`.

Is it possible to query an association table in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables can be queried just like declarative models.  The query returns a list of keyed tuples rather than instances of a class.

```
session.query(my_table).all()
```